# Hadoop on Azure using IaaS

Tags: azure, hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, azure-data-lake

I am looking at having a Hadoop cluster setup for Big Data analytics using the virtualized environment in Azure. As the data volume is very high, I am looking at having data stored in secondary storage like Azure Data Lake Store and Hadoop cluster storage will act as the primary storage. 
I would like to know, how can this be configured so that when i create a Hive table and partition, part of the data can reside in Primary storage and the rest in the secondary storage?

Thanks
Regards,
Madhu

Answer (score 3):

You can't mix file systems with a Hive table by default. The Hive metastore only consists of one filesystem  location for a database / table definition.

You might try to use [Waggle Dance](https://github.com/HotelsDotCom/waggle-dance) to setup a federated Hive solution, but it's probably too much work than simply allowing Hive data  to exist in Azure

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Hadoop and Hive but you could combine Azure Data Lake Store (ADLS) and Azure SQL Data Warehouse (ADW), ie use Polybase in ADW to create an external table on the 'cold' data in ADLS and an internal table for your 'warm' data.  ADW has the advantage that you can pause it.

Optionally create a view over the top to combine the external and internal table.